# How to install Google Camera on Nokia TA-1053

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android, apk

My phone Nokia TA-1053 is almost stock android with a couple of apps from them here and there. I really dislike their camera app. So, I tried to install Google Camera(since all other apps are from Google).

Now Google Camera app is not available in Play Store(at least for my phone). So I tried to side-load it from Apkmirror. My phone's android version in 9 and it supports API 28.

I downloaded the apk, installed it and when I was trying to open it, the app just won't open. It instantly shuts down the app and shows error messages. What should I do?

Comment: As far as I know Google Camera app is limited to Google Pixel devices, therefore it does not work on other devices. Modified versions can be found on the Internet that allows to use them on non-Pixel device, but you never know what else was modified on such apps. Therefore better check the common camera apps like [OpenCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera).

Comment: @Robert I think Google Camera can be installed (on custom ROM) with Open GApps, but they have a FAQ for Google Camera installation: [I read that 'Google Camera can only be installed during a Clean Install or as an update to an existing Open GApps Installation.' What does this mean?](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ#7-i-read-that-google-camera-can-only-be-installed-during-a-clean-install-or-as-an-update-to-an-existing-open-gapps-installation-what-does-this-mean).